# Mouse actions possible on all id tags on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

What I want to do is, find all possible actions (click , hover, etc) on each element id on a web page.

Below is my effort towards it:

```
function executeInteractions($) {

    for (var interaction_count = 0; interaction_count < interactions.length; interaction_count++) {
        var obj = interactions[interaction_count];

        for (var event_count = 0; event_count < obj.events.length; event_count++) {
            (function(elem, event_name, e_count, i_count, t_i_count) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    elem.trigger(event_name);
                    var sendData = {id : elem.attr('id') , event_n: event_name }
                    &.post("link#",sendData)

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        }
                    }, 10);

                    if (i_count + 1 >= t_i_count) {
                        window.interactionsComplete = true;
                    }
                }, 500 * i_count);
            }(obj.item, obj.events[event_count], event_count, interaction_count, interactions.length));
        }
    }
}

function findInteractions($) {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    var node, toBeProcessed = new Array;
    toBeProcessed.push($('body')[0]);
    while (toBeProcessed.length) {
        node = $(toBeProcessed.pop());
        var eventObject = node.data('events');
        if (eventObject) {
            var events = [];
            for (var e in eventObject) {
                events.push(e);
            }
            interactions.push({
                'item': node,
                'events': events
            });
        }
        var childrens = node.children();
        if (childrens && childrens.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; ++i) {
                toBeProcessed.push(childrens[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

window.interactions = [];
```

When the post request is received at the server end, I get lot of null values for id.

Can someone help me out here, or may be suggest any other efficient method to capture all possible actions on id elements on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply unique class to each attribute on page and then write `.click()/.mouseover()` JQuery event on it.

**HTML**:

```
<p class="uniqueClass">1st para</p>
<p class="uniqueClass">2nd para</p>
```

**JQuery code**:

```
<script>
   $( ".uniqueClass" ).click(function() {
     alert("Clicked");
   });
</script>
```

**For mouse over**, you can use .mouseover() function like:

```
<script>
   $( ".uniqueClass" ).mouseover(function() {
     alert("Mouse Over");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually i cannot make edits to the page, element id is all i have to use.

Comment: Then you may want to write on each type of element, like $( "p" ).click(function() {

Comment: But this will give me a success even if i am clicking on an id , lets say page title. but i need only those element id's which support clicks and hovers.

Comment: I think I am getting lost. You said you want to know all clicks on any elements through out your webpage. Above solution/comment will solve your problem.

Comment: I want to find the possible actions on an element id.
For example, if it's an image then "hover" is the action for it.
If its a link, then "click" action 
this is what i am looking for .

Comment: This is tricky, you need to set rules before that. For ex. consider only input action on textfield, only click action on button etc. After you setup rules, you can then use my above mentioned solution.